# Sending content directly to scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy. In my current project I am capturing the text from pdf files. I want to send this to a pipeline for parsing. Right now I have:

```
def get_pdf_text(self, response):
    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body))
    in_memory_pdf.seek(0)
    doc = slate.PDF(in_memory_pdf)
    item =OveItem()
    item['pdf_text']=doc
    return item
```

pipelines.py

```
class OvePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       .......
        return item
```

This works ,but I think it would be cleaner just to yield the result directly and not have to attach the result to an item to get it to a pipeline, like:

```
def get_pdf_text(self, response):
    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body))
    in_memory_pdf.seek(0)
    yield slate.PDF(in_memory_pdf)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse), a spider callback has to either return a `Request` instance(s), dictionary(ies) or `Item` instance(s):

> This method, as well as any other Request callback, must return an
>   iterable of Request and/or dicts or Item objects.

So, if you don't want to define a special "item" for the pdf content, simply wrap it into a dict:

```
def get_pdf_text(self, response):
    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(bytes(response.body))
    in_memory_pdf.seek(0)

    doc = slate.PDF(in_memory_pdf)

    return {'pdf_text': doc}
```